Azure Databricks Linked Services Creation via Powershell dataSecurityMode not append
I try to run this command to Create Azure Databricks Linked Services
Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -Force -ResourceGroupName MYDEVRESOURCEGROUP -DataFactoryName MYDEVADF -Name LS_ADB_JOB_01 -DefinitionFile ./LS_ADB_JOB_01.json

LS_ADB_JOB_01.json is containing content
        .
        .
        .
            "newClusterSparkEnvVars": {
                "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
            },
            "newClusterVersion": "@linkedService().ClusterVersion",
            "newClusterDriverNodeType": "@linkedService().DriverNodeType",
            "clusterOption": "Autoscaling",
            "newClusterInitScripts": [
                "/Workspace/Ingestion/init_odbc_driver.sh"
            ],
            "dataSecurityMode": "SINGLE_USER"
        },
        .
        .
        .

Then this command is run successfully but "dataSecurityMode": "SINGLE_USER" is not appear on ADF

How can I fix this?

are you geting any error?

No error it successfully run.

I have tried to create AzureDatabrick linked service in Azure Data Factory with latest PowerShell and Az module version.

When I checked it from Azure Datafactory UI  "dataSecurityMode": "SINGLE_USER" and "clusterOption": "Autoscaling" these two parameters are missing.

This can be a bug to workaround this you can use Rest API to update the Linked service
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/pdstackdemo/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pdstackadf/linkedservices/LS_ADB_JOB_01?api-version=2018-06-01

body:
{
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "Cluster_version": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "Cluster_Node_Type": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "Driver_node_type": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureDatabricks",
        "typeProperties": {
            "domain": "https://adb-762.8.azuredatabricks.net",
            "newClusterNodeType": "@linkedService().Cluster_Node_Type",
            "newClusterNumOfWorker": "2:4",
            "newClusterSparkEnvVars": {
                "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
            },
            "newClusterVersion": "@linkedService().Cluster_version",
            "newClusterDriverNodeType": "@linkedService().Driver_node_type",
            "clusterOption": "Autoscaling",
            "newClusterInitScripts": [],
            "dataSecurityMode": "SINGLE_USER"
        }
    }
}

This will Update the linked service with all appropriate parameters:

